# The R package BosonSampling keeps running without result

Tags: r

I tried to generate boson sampling data using R package BosonSampling. Although it takes long time to generate samples for larger values of n and m, I tried smaller values but I didn't get any output from code. I don't know what is the problem.

The documentation is available in the link:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BosonSampling/index.html

the code from documentation:

```
library('BosonSampling')
library('Rcpp')
set.seed(7) 
n <- 10
m <- 20
A <- randomUnitary(m)[,1:n]
valueList <- bosonSampler(A, sampleSize=10, perm = FALSE)$values
valueList
```

Comment: This works fine for me (R-devel on Linux, `BosonSampling` 0.1.3).  Is this in a clean R session? Can you post the results of `sessionInfo()` ? (you shouldn't need `library("Rcpp")`)

Comment: Works fine on a Linux box running R 4.2.0 and BosonSampling 0.1.3. The response was very quick,much less than one second for that code. My computer is several years old so I'm not running some exotic fast CPU. I'm going to vote to close as not having sufficient information to debug.